# Go Tools installed successfully but not appear in $GOPATH/bin

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I installed go tools in vscode and the terminal showed that the tools are installed successfully:

```
Tools environment: GOPATH=/home/spindrift/go
Installing 1 tool at /home/spindrift/go/bin in module mode.
  gopls

Installing golang.org/x/tools/gopls (gopls) SUCCEEDED

All tools successfully installed. You are ready to Go :).
```

But after installing the vscode keep showing `gopls is inquired but missing`

So I take a look at $GOPATH/bin, and there's only `dlv-dap` in it!

I check my configured tools:

```
Checking configured tools....
GOBIN: undefined
toolsGopath: 
gopath: /home/spindrift/go
GOROOT: /usr/local/go
PATH: /usr/local/go/bin:/home/spindrift/.vscode-server/bin/ea3859d4ba2f3e577a159bc91e3074c5d85c0523/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/wsl/lib:/mnt/c/Program Files/WindowsApps/Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_1.12.10732.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe:/mnt/c/WINDOWS:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/DevelopTools/Maven/apache-maven-3.2.5/bin:/mnt/c/DevelopTools/mingw64/mingw64/bin:/mnt/c/DevelopTools/Matlab2018a/runtime/win64:/mnt/c/DevelopTools/Matlab2018a/bin:/mnt/c/DevelopTools/Lingo/:/mnt/c/DevelopTools/MongoDB/Server/bin:/mnt/c/DevelopTools/Git/cmd:/mnt/c/DevelopTools/mysql/bin:/mnt/c/DevelopTools/anaconda3:/mnt/c/DevelopTools/anaconda3/Scripts:/mnt/c/DevelopTools/anaconda3/Library/bin:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32:/mnt/c/DevelopTools/Go/bin:/mnt/c/DevelopTools/scala/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/dotnet/:/mnt/c/Users/Libra/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/DevelopTools/VSCode/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/mnt/c/Software/Bandizip/:/mnt/c/Users/Libra/AppData/Roaming/npm:/mnt/c/DevelopTools/nodejs:/mnt/c/Users/Libra/go/bin:/mnt/c/Users/Libra/.dotnet/tools:/snap/bin
PATH (vscode launched with): /home/spindrift/.vscode-server/bin/ea3859d4ba2f3e577a159bc91e3074c5d85c0523/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/wsl/lib:/mnt/c/Program Files/WindowsApps/Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_1.12.10732.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe:/mnt/c/WINDOWS:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/DevelopTools/Maven/apache-maven-3.2.5/bin:/mnt/c/DevelopTools/mingw64/mingw64/bin:/mnt/c/DevelopTools/Matlab2018a/runtime/win64:/mnt/c/DevelopTools/Matlab2018a/bin:/mnt/c/DevelopTools/Lingo/:/mnt/c/DevelopTools/MongoDB/Server/bin:/mnt/c/DevelopTools/Git/cmd:/mnt/c/DevelopTools/mysql/bin:/mnt/c/DevelopTools/anaconda3:/mnt/c/DevelopTools/anaconda3/Scripts:/mnt/c/DevelopTools/anaconda3/Library/bin:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32:/mnt/c/DevelopTools/Go/bin:/mnt/c/DevelopTools/scala/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/dotnet/:/mnt/c/Users/Libra/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/DevelopTools/VSCode/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/mnt/c/Software/Bandizip/:/mnt/c/Users/Libra/AppData/Roaming/npm:/mnt/c/DevelopTools/nodejs:/mnt/c/Users/Libra/go/bin:/mnt/c/Users/Libra/.dotnet/tools:/snap/bin:/usr/local/go/bin

    go: /usr/local/go/bin/go: go version go1.18.1 linux/amd64

    gopkgs: not installed
    go-outline: not installed
    gotests:    not installed
    gomodifytags:   not installed
    impl:   not installed
    goplay: not installed
    dlv:    not installed
    dlv-dap:    /home/spindrift/go/bin/dlv-dap: go1.18.1
        path    github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv
        mod github.com/go-delve/delve   v1.8.3-0.20220413222856-313815782614    h1:J92Zq5+vc+zzd0Gn69RxVUUC3orKgciGmurMPUSci4I=
        dep github.com/cilium/ebpf  v0.7.0  h1:1k/q3ATgxSXRdrmPfH8d7YK0GfqVsEKZAX9dQZvs56k=
        dep github.com/cosiner/argv v0.1.0  h1:BVDiEL32lwHukgJKP87btEPenzrrHUjajs/8yzaqcXg=
        dep github.com/cpuguy83/go-md2man/v2    v2.0.0  h1:EoUDS0afbrsXAZ9YQ9jdu/mZ2sXgT1/2yyNng4PGlyM=
        dep github.com/derekparker/trie v0.0.0-20200317170641-1fdf38b7b0e9  h1:G765iDCq7bP5opdrPkXk+4V3yfkgV9iGFuheWZ/X/zY=
        dep github.com/go-delve/liner   v1.2.2-1    h1:0hGpZh6vjI6LFTlXuHFCX9PebaluzDzps2owdMrrSuk=
        dep github.com/google/go-dap    v0.6.0  h1:Y1RHGUtv3R8y6sXq2dtGRMYrFB2hSqyFVws7jucrzX4=
        dep github.com/hashicorp/golang-lru v0.5.4  h1:YDjusn29QI/Das2iO9M0BHnIbxPeyuCHsjMW+lJfyTc=
        dep github.com/mattn/go-isatty  v0.0.3  h1:ns/ykhmWi7G9O+8a448SecJU3nSMBXJfqQkl0upE1jI=
        dep github.com/mattn/go-runewidth   v0.0.13 h1:lTGmDsbAYt5DmK6OnoV7EuIF1wEIFAcxld6ypU4OSgU=
        dep github.com/rivo/uniseg  v0.2.0  h1:S1pD9weZBuJdFmowNwbpi7BJ8TNftyUImj/0WQi72jY=
        dep github.com/russross/blackfriday/v2  v2.0.1  h1:lPqVAte+HuHNfhJ/0LC98ESWRz8afy9tM/0RK8m9o+Q=
        dep github.com/shurcooL/sanitized_anchor_name   v1.0.0  h1:PdmoCO6wvbs+7yrJyMORt4/BmY5IYyJwS/kOiWx8mHo=
        dep github.com/sirupsen/logrus  v1.6.0  h1:UBcNElsrwanuuMsnGSlYmtmgbb23qDR5dG+6X6Oo89I=
        dep github.com/spf13/cobra  v1.1.3  h1:xghbfqPkxzxP3C/f3n5DdpAbdKLj4ZE4BWQI362l53M=
        dep github.com/spf13/pflag  v1.0.5  h1:iy+VFUOCP1a+8yFto/drg2CJ5u0yRoB7fZw3DKv/JXA=
        dep go.starlark.net v0.0.0-20200821142938-949cc6f4b097  h1:YiRMXXgG+Pg26t1fjq+iAjaauKWMC9cmGFrtOEuwDDg=
        dep golang.org/x/arch   v0.0.0-20190927153633-4e8777c89be4  h1:QlVATYS7JBoZMVaf+cNjb90WD/beKVHnIxFKT4QaHVI=
        dep golang.org/x/sys    v0.0.0-20211117180635-dee7805ff2e1  h1:kwrAHlwJ0DUBZwQ238v+Uod/3eZ8B2K5rYsUHBQvzmI=
        dep gopkg.in/yaml.v2    v2.4.0  h1:D8xgwECY7CYvx+Y2n4sBz93Jn9JRvxdiyyo8CTfuKaY=
        build   -compiler=gc
        build   CGO_ENABLED=1
        build   CGO_CFLAGS=
        build   CGO_CPPFLAGS=
        build   CGO_CXXFLAGS=
        build   CGO_LDFLAGS=
        build   GOARCH=amd64
        build   GOOS=linux
        build   GOAMD64=v1
    
    staticcheck:    not installed
    gopls:  not installed
```

It seems that I failed to install go tools. I tried several times but the problem still unsolved.

Here's my `go env`

```
GO111MODULE="auto"
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/home/spindrift/.cache/go-build"
GOENV="/home/spindrift/.config/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOEXPERIMENT=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/home/spindrift/go/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/spindrift/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://goproxy.cn,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.18.1"
GCCGO="gccgo"
GOAMD64="v1"
AR="ar"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD=""
GOWORK=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build1163911802=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

Comment: I don't know if vscode checks it internally, but `/home/spindrift/go/bin` is not in your PATH.

Comment: since `$GOBIN` is not defined, these binaries could be in `$GOTOOLDIR` or `$GROOT/bin`

Comment: I add /home/spindrift/go/bin in PATH but the problem remains

Comment: Strange. If you run `go install -x -v golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest` from your terminal from the vscode integrated terminal in the session, does it say where it is installing gopls?

Comment: It says `Installing 1 tool at /home/spindrift/go/bin in module mode.`. But actually there's nothing in this path after installing. @Hana

Comment: @LibraTang I meant to try the go command (`go install -x -v ...`) to see if that helps or you can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug in the go extension which occurs when using go 1.18. It has been fixed in recent versions of vscode-go, for details see [1] and [2].

Updating vscode **and** the go extension (vscode-go) should resolve your problem (as it did for me).

[1] https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/issues/2143

[2] https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/commit/656865daa974f43e8e88310e5076f3f0c4936c73

Comment: It solves my confusion. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

GOBIN is not present in your $PATH.

the easiest way is to add one more line to your .bashrc / .zshrc in $HOME
`PATH = $PATH:$HOME`

learn more on $PATH [here](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)

Comment: I add GOBIN in $PATH but the problem remain

Comment: Maybe it's not applied yet. You need to restart your terminal or use the command `source YOUR_SOURCE_FILE` to apply (with `YOUR_SOURCE FILE` is `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`) @LibraTang

Comment: I'm sure it's applied.

Comment: The problem not related to issues with the PATH variable, it is caused by a bug in the go extension which has been fixed by now.

Answer (score 0):

Some configurations are fetched from "GOENV" file.
Make sure params in that file are valid, Especially look for "GOROOT" in it.
It should exactly match your GO executable path. (In most cases it could be /usr/local/go)

If not valid, update values and try again.

Answer (score -1):

The gopls is present in GOPATH and GOROOT, but still VS Code complains about not being able to find gopls.

Configured tools output shows gopls and other tools properly installed.
go version 1.17.12

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32379515)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).